# HTML input tag Date

Tags: php, html

Doubt in HTML. I want to select a date from a Date Picker. When i select a day with the help of a date picker, date is shown 08/17/2016 (i.e month/day/year ). It should be displayed as 17/08/2016 (i.e day/month/year). could anyone please help me to clarify this doubt with an example code.
Here is my html coding part:

Comment: Which date picker are you using?

Comment: Using HTML5 date picker.. This is my coding part    <input type="date" name="date" value="2016_12_31">